# How to apply indexing to IEnumerable expression type and display data side-by-side in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, indexing, foreach

I am working on a Asp.net MVC application and came across a scenario where I have to display the contents in two columns (i.e., side by side) I googled and came across a solution here. I tried but a vain attempt.
I tried this way

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.tblTest>

@{

ViewBag.Title = "Index";

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<h2>Index</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
    <th>
        testId
    </th>
    <th>
        testName
    </th>
    <th>
        testDescription
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i+=2 )
{
<tr>
    <td>
       @Model[i].testId
    </td>


</tr>
}

</table>
```

But I got a compilation error --
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type       

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.tblTest>'

Source Error:


Line 27:     <tr>
Line 28:         <td>
Line 29:            @Model[i].testId
Line 30:         </td>
Line 31:
```

Could anyone please assist me in solving this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply, you can't index an enumerable. It's designed to spit out one item at a time in order, not a specific item from anywhere in the stack. The simplest solution is to cast it to a `List`:

```
@{
    var tblTestList = Model.ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < tblTestList.Count(); i+=2 )
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @tblTestList[i].testId
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.tblTest>
```

Comment: using @model List<T> was definitely easier

Answer (score 4):

IEnumerable doesn't per se contains all items ready to be used, it could be based on a query that might run later so indexers are not available.

However, there are different ways you can achieve the same.

**.ToList() or .ToArray()**

You can convert your IEnumerable to List or T[] by using the extension methods provided by default in System.Linq

```
@Model.ToList()[i].testId
```

or

```
@Model.ToArray()[i].testId
```

This may require the entire query to rerun every time you do a .ToList() or a ToArray()

So it is recommended to create a List/Array collection once use that collection for your iterations.

Since IEnumerable provides a basic iterator it would be much easier to use them in base classes.

e.g.,

```
    protected void MyIterator<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        //Iteration here 
    }
```

This can be called by anyone by passing a Query / List / Array

```
MyIterator(from i in AllItems where i == '' select i);
```

or

```
MyIterator(new List<T>());
```

or

```
MyIterator(new T[]{});
```

Under these circumstances you could use the ElementAt(int) indexer available on IEnumerable. E.g.,

```
 protected void MyIterator<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
 {
            //Iteration here 
    T item = items.ElementAt(3);//4th item in the items collection. 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good spot for a for a foreach loop

```
@foreach(var m in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>m.testId</td>
    <td>m.testName</td>
    <td>m.testDescription</td>
</tr>
}
```